# Encapsulate algorithm configuration in system hierarchy

Tags: design, configuration, configuration-management

Say, I'm building a system that **uses** various complex algorithms (k means, mean shift, a few others), all of which are parameterized.  I'm highlighting `uses', because the system is not just a thin layer around them; deep in its processing, these algorithms are instantiated and executed.

The 'dumb' parts of the system don't need to and shouldn't know about the specific parameters required by these algorithms, but somehow these algorithms need to get their parameters from some central configuration.

What are good strategies to determine the source of the configuration on a system level, but avoid passing individual parameters through several layers of the software to where they are needed?

I'm thinking either dependency injection magic or an unspecific configuration object (eg. a map) that is passed around.  The former seems a bit of a large liability for so trivial a task, the latter doesn't fully eliminate the need to have parameters handled by code that shouldn't be concerned with them.

Comment: This is far from being trivial task. And you should take it as such. I'm voting to close as "too broad", because how to implement this depends heavily on type of parameters and how they are input into the system.

Comment: I think in order to make this question less broad you could include some contrived code snippets showing a similar pattern to the one you find in your app

Answer (score 0):

The way that I have been handling this in my projects is that first of all, I always maintain a clear distinction between what is application-specific (domain-specific) code and what is general-purpose code.  Your algorithms can be thought of, I suppose, as general-purpose code.

The configuration is loaded by the root application class (the 'application' object) and stored in an application-specific structure.  This is not a generic map, it is an actual structure with individual, strongly typed fields, with long names explaining precisely what each value stands for.  All application-specific code generally has a reference to the application object, so it is free to obtain this structure from it.

The application may consist of subsystems or modules.  Each module can be thought of in turn as another application, with its own configuration structure, which usually contains a subset of the fields of the main application's configuration structure.  For each module, I gladly suffer the pain of passing the pertinent fields of the main application's structure so they can be stored in the fields of the subsystem's configuration structure.  Luckily, the number of subsystems is not all that large, so this does not represent a major pain.

At the moment that I cross the boundary between application-specific code and general-purpose code, I always pass every single value as a distinct, strongly typed, properly named parameter to every single method or constructor that needs it, and from that moment on I gladly suffer the pain of propagating these parameters as many levels deep as necessary.

True, these parameters are often altered, (some are added, some are dropped, names or types change, etc.) so there is a bit of typing involved, but our main bottleneck in our profession is not typing; it is management of complexity.  Which requires clarity.  So, this mechanism pays.